# How to handle multi-task in one process using theano for machine learning?

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

I have a CNN model. The requests of using this model, for example to classify a picture, come 1 time a second.

I would like to collect the requests as new unsuperised data, and keep training my model.

My question is: How can I handle the training task and classify task effictively?

I will explain why it becomes a problem:

Every training step takes a long time, at least severy seconds, using GPU and not interruptable. So, if my classify tasks use GPU too, I cannot response the requests in time. I would like to make classify tasks using CPU, but looks like theano not support two diffrent config.device in one process.

Multi-process is not acceptable, because my memory is limited and theano costs too much.

Any help or advice would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could build two separate copies of the same CNN, one on the CPU and one on the GPU.  I think this could be done under either the old GPU backend or the new one, but in different ways....some ideas:

Under the old backend:

Load Theano with `device=cpu`.  Build your inference function and compile it.  Then call `theano.sandbox.cuda.use('gpu')`, and build a new copy of your inference function and take gradients of that one to make any training functions.  Now the inference function should execute on the CPU, and the training should happen on the GPU.  (I've never done this on purpose but I had it happen to me on accident!)

Under the new backend:

As far as I know, you have to tell Theano about any GPUs right when importing, not later.  In this case, you could use `THEANO_FLAGS="contexts=dev0->cuda0"`, which doesn't force using one device over another.  Then build the inference version of your function like normal, and for the training version, again put all the shared variables on the GPU, and the input variables to any of your training functions should also be GPU variables (e.g. `input_var_1.transfer('dev0')`).  When all your functions are compiled, look at the programs using `theano.printing.debugprint(function)` to see what's on GPU vs CPU.  (When compiling the CPU functions, it might give a warning that it cannot infer the context, and as far as I've seen, that lands it on the CPU...not sure if this behavior is safe to depend on.)

In either case, this will depend on your GPU-based functions do NOT RETURN ANYTHING TO THE CPU (make sure the output variables are GPU ones).  This should allow the training function to run concurrently to your inference function, and later you grab what you need to the CPU.  For example when you take a training step, just copy the new values over to your inference network parameters, of course.

Let us hear what you come up with!